# WHY UIPanGestureRecognizer has weird move distance DELAY?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a vary simple case:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
  testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  testView.center = self.view.center;
  [self.view addSubview:testView];

  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
  [testView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];

  UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGes = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
  [testView addGestureRecognizer:panGes];
}

- (void)handlePan:(MMUIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGes {
  panGes.view.center = [panGes locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGR {
  tapGR.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random() % 2 green:arc4random() % 2 blue:arc4random() % 2 alpha:1.0];
}
```

> Explain

It's very simple.Just add a UITapGestureRecognizer and a UIPanGestureRecognizer,and each gestureRecognizer binds a action.

But, the weird thing is that,if you move your finger slowly(**very very slowly**), you can see the red testView don't move at all.It just begin to move once the distance you finger moved is more than about **5px**. That's puzzle! SO, how to make the testView responses finger moving instantly with any delay.

I made some work. One of ways is subclass UIPanGesture named **MMUIPanGestureRecognizer**, it actually solve the delay issue and the testView responses finger moving instantly.But,another weird thing coming.***It prevent all of gestures except the MMUIPanGestureRecognizer***. Holy xxx!

I push my simple test project to Github,you can check out [Here](https://github.com/KittenYang/UIPanGestureDelayBugDemo).

Thanks for helping indeed!

Comment: The pan gesture is probably waiting for the tap gesture recognizer to fail before it starts being recognized.

Comment: You are wrong.Actually I remove the tap gesture and let testView only has single UITapGestureRecognizer, it still has delay.

Comment: The pan gesture recognizer is probably written that way so that it doesn't pick up what should be a long press. (Your finger is likely to drift slightly if you press and hold.) In order to get a pan gesture without a delay you might need to create your own custom gesture recognizer. It's not actually that hard.

Comment: @DuncanC I actually did it, you can check the test project:[Demo](https://github.com/KittenYang/UIPanGestureDelayBugDemo) ,I subclassed a UIPanGesture, it fix the delay issus but it prevent all another gesture.

Comment: Preventing other gestures is the trade-off. In order to use your modified gesture recognizer you'd need to limit it to small areas of the screen where you don't need taps, swipes, or other gestures.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're going to answer your own question ([which is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) with your `MMUIPanGestureRecognizer` class, I'd suggest posting that as an answer to your question, rather including it in your question, itself. It preserves the Q&A structure of Stack Overflow.